# Create a sorted list from an unsorted list in excel using if and array

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I got stuck trying to do some organisation in my excel sheet. Hope someone can help me. Thank you.

I know how to use a nested if statement for an array but there's something I am not able to figure out.

I have an unsorted list:

```
No | ITEM   | Cost | Category 
#1 | item 1 | $10  |    A
#1 | item 2 | $30  |    C
#2 | item 3 | $70  |    A
#3 | item 4 | $20  |    B
#4 | item 5 | $50  |    B
```

I want to sort them into 3 seperate list on the right side of the excel sheet. Category A, B and C

Category A

```
ITEM   | Cost
item 1 | $10
item 3 | $70
```

Category B

```
ITEM   | Cost
item 4 | $20
item 5 | $50
```

Category C

```
ITEM   | Cost
item 2 | $30
```

What I did initially was to use an array in a nested if statement on the individual cell in the sorted list.

For example,

```
 =IF(D1 : D5="A", B1, "")
```

But it doesn't sort out properly and display error. I have hundreds over items and it is a bit hard to go through them everytime I want to look up something. The list cannot be sorted using the "sort" in excel because I want the unsorted list to be arranged by dates.

Sorry for the trouble, I just need someone to teach me how to do it one of the sorted category and I should figure out the rest on my own. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following array formula in `F3` cell as below screenshot. Then drag right 1 cell and drop below as required. For `Category B` You have to enter same formula in `I3` cell just changing `A to B`.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B$2:B$6,SMALL(IF($D$2:$D$6="A",ROW($D$2:$D$6)-ROW($D$1),""),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

> Note: You must press ***CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER*** after typing formula.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I manage to do it for F3. But when I try to do the formula on F4, it returns a blank value instead of "item3" (which is the next category A item) What should I change? Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi harun! I managed to make the right changes but it is displaying "inconsistent formula" on cell F4 (it displays item1 instead of item3).

Comment: I would also like to ask the significance of "ROW($D$2:$D$6)-ROW($D$1)" and ROW(1:1). What do they do in the INDEX function? Thank you.

Comment: When you put formula in `F3` cell correctly, then just drag and drop to down. No need to type formula again again.

Comment: `ROW($D$2:$D$6)-ROW($D$1)` create an array of rows containing `A` and `ROW(1:1)` is for first element of array. When you drag it to down one cell then it will `ROW(2:2)` means it will put second element of array and so on.

Comment: Hi Harun! Thank you so much for your help! It saved me a lot of time. I appreciate it. Last question! The part about ROW($D$1) after the minus sign, what does it do? Thank you so much.

Comment: When your data starts from row 2 means `B2 or C2 or D2` then `-ROW($D$1)` will always minus 1 from row numbers of B2, B3, B4 (row(B2)=2, row(B3)=3, row(B4)=4) so that `Index()` function can correct row number of dataset from array.

Comment: Now I understand what's going on! Thank you so much for your help Harun. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Alas, it's easy job in Google Spreadsheet since it provides `query()`.

When `1:1` is `No, ITEM, Cost, Category`, and `B:B` is `ITEM, item1, item2, ...`, let's put output in `F:K`, so `F1:G1` is `Category, A`, `H1:I1` is `Category, B`, and `J1:K1` is `Category, C`. Now input below array formula at `F2:G2`. (Note that `G$1` is `'A'`)

```
{=IF($D2=G$1, $B2:$C2, "")}
```

Now copy `F2:G2` and paste at `F3:G6`. And then copy `F2:G6` and paste at `H2:K6`.
Now you can sort `F:G` for category A, `H:I` for category B, `J:K` for category C.

Comment: If you're not familiar with array formula, do [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=excel+array+formula) and learn it first.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$6,SMALL(IF($D$1:$D$6="A",ROW($D$1:$D$6)),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

Note that this is an array formula for a single cell only. Confirm the formula in a cell in row 2 using `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` and then fill the formula down the remaining cells.

This formula works using the SMALL function. It starts by finding the first lowest ROW number of the D column that contains the value "A". Then when the formula is filled down, you'll next find the second lowest ROW of the D column that contains the value "A" and so on. The Index function returns the value from the Item column at the found ROW number.

Comment: Thank you! I can understand part of the formula but can you explain the last part row (1:1) what is that? Thank you!

Comment: Hi Michael. Thank you very much for your help. I understand how to use the formula already. :)